# How can I image an iBook G4 drive?

Tags: backup, powerpc

I have an iBook G4 (identified as a PowerBook6,7 with 1GB of RAM) with Japanese OS. I want to make a backup of it.

I downloaded an old Ubuntu 6 ISO and booted it. First problem is that the battery is dead, so the clock resets to 1980, and on booting most of the apps crash. After quitting them all and opening a terminal, I tried to image the drive with the following command:

`sudo dd if=/dev/hda conv=sync,noerror bs=128k | split -b 2000m - /media/usbdrive/image.dd.`

I was able to make backup images to a FAT32 formatted USB stick, but there is always filesystem corruption. I tried two different sticks and an SSD, all failed with the same issue. I have one complete image but I don't know if it's good or corrupt.

In an attempt to determine if it was good, I used md5sum with dd. The value from `dd if=/dev/hda conv=sync,noerror bs=128k | md5sum` was different to all the images I made, corrupt or otherwise.

I tried Lubuntu 16.04, but it won't boot. It gets to the desktop and hangs. Is Ubuntu Server 16.04 worth trying?

​Is there some free Mac software that can do this? Basically I just need to create a drive image that I can restore later if needs be. I don't want to take the drive out because it's a real pain on these iBooks. Bonus points if the imaging solution can show a progress bar.

Comment: Have you verified that the ***source*** is clean and un-corrupted?  `dd` does a block level copy of your drive so the destination format should not matter.

Comment: Also, instead of splitting the image, try removing the drive and connecting it to the your Linux or newer Mac with a USB to PATA adapter and then make an image of the whole drive. In one go.

Comment: @Allan I'm not sure how I can do that, other than DD not reporting any errors. Can you recommend some software for testing the internal hard drive for read errors? It does boot the OS.

Comment: @Allan I'm trying to avoid removing the drive as it is a major pain in the arse. I don't have a newer Mac but I'm sure I could image it on a PC with Clonezilla or DD.

Comment: `dd` won’t report errors as it does ***block level*** copying. In other words, it copies whatever is on the block corrupted or not.  Can you get a larger USB drive?  The idea is to not split the image?

Comment: @Allan the image has to be split because FAT32 has a 4GB size limit and that version of Linux doesn't have NTFS write support. I thought about trying EXT3 because Windows can read that with an app. I'm not sure what Mac OS 10.4 can read, but I'm guessing FAT32 support is included.

Comment: The file format doesn’t matter; `dd` [does block level copying](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1139051/copy-data-at-the-block-level)

Comment: @Allan no I'm saying I'm trying to save it to a FAT32 formatted USB drive. I need to be able to access the image to archive it somehow after I have made it. The only Mac I have is this iBook so it makes more sense to store it somewhere that a Windows machine can read it, then I can compress it and stick it in my backup system.

Comment: Then use ExFAT use whatever Linux likes The format does not matter. Don’t split the file because it adds complexity.

Comment: @Allan That version of Linux doesn't support ExFAT. I have been unable to get any newer versions that might support it to boot. No joy with MintPPC as the USB drive is not recognized by the firmware.

Comment: If you use a larger USB, you can then take it to a modern computer and image that to a file.